# How do I solve this "Invalid property value" problem?

Tags: css, sass, web-frontend

I added gradient effect to text which is working perfectly fine on firefox but on chrome and my phone (safari ios) the gradient effect just do not work. Inspect element gives yellow flag (invalid property value) for two properties which are background: linear-gradient(left, #38d39f, #38a4d3) and background-clip: text
I use SCSS[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bINCQ.jpg).

```
  h2 {
    font-size: 8rem;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    background: $gradient;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-clip: text;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Comment: it's `to left` and not `left` and you also need `-webkit-background-clip: text;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background-clip` property is not yet supported on Chrome without the `-webkit` prefix.

And the `linear-gradient()` side value should have the `to` keyword rather than just `left`.

With those additions, it should look something like this:

```
$gradient: linear-gradient(to left, #f542f5, #999);

h2 {
  font-size: 8rem;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  background: $gradient;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Reference: [Can I Use - background clip](https://caniuse.com/?search=background-clip), [MDN - CSS gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()#values)